# How to set up kaminari correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

I'm using kaminari gem for pagination. The problem is that I need to paginate on the first page after 4 elements, and on the all other pages after 25 elements. It it possible to configure kaminari to solve my problem?
Here is a usage:

```
.pagination
  .pagination__back
    - if params[:page] && params[:page].to_i > 1
      = link_to "Previous news", news_items_path(page: params[:page].to_i - 1)
    - else
      = ""
  .pagination__forward
    - if params[:page]
      = link_to "Next news", news_items_path(page: params[:page].to_i + 1)
    - else
      = link_to "Next news", news_items_path(page: 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can leave out all the code related to forward/previous pages. Kaminari solves this with its helper already.
For that matter, inside your view, use the following code:

```
= paginate @your_resource
```

> This will render several ?page=N pagination links surrounded by an HTML5  tag.
>   ([Source](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#views))

To have a paginated resource, you want to add the following code to your controller:

```
@your_resource = YourResource.order(:foobar).page(params[:page])
# params[:page] will get added to each "paginated" request by Kaminari 
# if you use its previously mentioned helper method.
```

Now you want a dynamic limit. For that matter I suggest adding something like this:

```
def index
  @your_resource = YourResource.order(:foobar).page(params[:page]).per(dynamic_limit(params[:page]))
end

private
def dynamic_limit(current_page = 1)
  if current_page == 1
    return 4
  else
    return 25
  end
end
```

This way you will check for the current page, and if it's the first page it'll limit the results to 4. Otherwise, 25.